# Sql Server - Invalid query because of no aggregate function or group by clause for comparing difference between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server

Given a table:

```
-------------------------------------
|  Id   | DateField_A | DateField_B |
-------------------------------------
|   1   |  2017-01-01 | 2018-06-01  |
-------------------------------------
|   2   |  2018-02-01 | 2018-06-01  |
-------------------------------------
|   3   |  2018-04-01 | 2018-04-03  |
-------------------------------------
```

I am trying to write a query that takes the sum of rows between a date range where two date fields are less than 5 days apart.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM TABLE
WHERE 
         DateField_A >= '2018-01-01'
     AND DateField_A < '2019-01-01'

     HAVING (DateField_B - DateField_A) <= 5
```

This would return **count 1** given the table above.

However I'm getting the following error:

[image]

How can I fix the query?

Comment: Remove the `HAVING` will fix your query.  How can you have `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `having` and `select` on fields that are included in a `group by` clause or included in an aggregate function such as `count`.  In your case, you just want to move that to your `where` criteria:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE DateField_A >= '2018-01-01'
     AND DateField_A < '2019-01-01'
     AND (DateField_B - DateField_A) <= 5
```

---

As commented below, please be careful when using subtraction or addition for comparing dates.  While it might work for this instance, you would be safer using date comparison functions such as `dateadd`, or in this case, `datediff`:

```
...
    AND datediff(day, datefield_a, datefield_b) <= 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: This solves the issue today but this still has some issues (leftover from the original query from the OP). Using addition on datetime columns is a bad habit. If you change to datetime2 your query suddenly stops working. Better to use DATEADD always. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: @SeanLange -- Good point, I wasn't even looking at the criteria that closely, just the error :)  I'll edit explaining the difference.  Thanks!